# Path issue in Angular2 app on github pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

I am new to Angular2 and intend to set up a small Angular2 app (helloworld currently) on github pages for startup.

I created `ng2-lite` via `angular-cli`, hosted at [site](https://moyummy.github.io/ng2-lite/). The deploy is provided by `angular-cli`. It deployed to `gh-pages` branch for display.

Recently I discovered another way other than `angular-cli`. I created `ng2-raw` from scratch with similar code but without any deploy operation, hosted at [site](https://moyummy.github.io/ng2-raw/helloworld/)

However I met some issues when creating `ng2-raw`. After debugging, it could not find `css` or `html` by relative path (which are under same path as `ts`), so I modified path to make it work.

Please check out the different code in my two repo:

github.com/MoYummy/ng2-lite/blob/master/src/app/hello.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./hello.component.css']
})
export class HelloComponent {
    name: string = 'World';
}
```

github.com/MoYummy/ng2-raw/blob/gh-pages/helloworld/app/hello.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    templateUrl: './app/hello.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/hello.component.css']
})
export class HelloComponent {
    name: string = 'ng2';
}
```

Why do I have to update those paths? What if the code structure becomes complex in future or if I try to move one component to a subfolder?

What is the difference between the two ways of deploying my Angular2 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting the author of this [repo](https://github.com/lewis617/angular2-tutorial), he told me his repo utilized `systemjs` to load js file.

His site is for simple demo so it is not suggested to deploy a lite version of ng2 app in this way. Instead `angular-cli` is better.

I would like to stop further exploration in [ng-raw](https://moyummy.github.io/ng2-raw/helloworld/).